# Prove $3+ 5 \sqrt {2}$ is irrational

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove $3+ 5 \sqrt{2}$ is irrational.

I have some ideas about this proof, but I am not quite finished. I understand being irrational means the number would not be in the form of $\frac pq$. I have proved root $2$ is irrational before, but am a bit confused with this one, any ideas. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If $x = 3 + 5 \sqrt{2}$ were rational, then so would be $(x-3)/5$.

Answer (score 4):

If $3+5\sqrt 2$ were rational, $\sqrt 2$ would be too.

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  You want the exact. Proof  then this is it.

Let $3+5/\sqrt{ 2}$  be rational.

$3+5/\sqrt{ 2}= p/q$

squaring both sides we get.  $(3+5/\sqrt{2})^2 =(p/q)^2$

$59+30/\sqrt2=(p/q)^2$

WE CAN WRITE:

$\sqrt2=(p^2-59q^2)/30q^2$

Lhs.   Irrational
Rhs.   Rational

Not possible. So. $3+5/\sqrt 2$ is irrational.

Answer (score 1):

Let the roots of a quadratic equation be $r_1 = 3 +5\sqrt{2}$ and $r_2 = 3 - 5\sqrt{2}$.

Then by [Vieta's formulas](https://brilliant.org/wiki/vietas-formula/), $-\frac{b}{a} = r_1 + r_2 = 6$, and $\frac{c}{a} = r_1 \cdot r_2 = -41$. Setting $a = 1$, the quadratic equation is $x^2+6x-41$.

By the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), *if the roots are not rational*, the numerator would need to divide $41$, and the denominator would need to divide $1$. The only possibilities therefore are $-41$ and $41$.

However, as these are not the roots of our quadratic, then **both** $3 + 5\sqrt{2}$ and $3 - 5\sqrt{2}$ are irrational.

Comment: Funnily enough, I was just browsing through this question myself :)

Comment: @user477343 The only reason I answered this question is because your edit put it on the front page :-)

Comment: Well, I'm glad we got people like you who like to do things a bit different. Everyone's answers here are pretty much the same, but yours is different. $(+1)$ :)